# Is there a way to convert a very large XML file with UTF8 encoding in powershell?

Tags: .net, performance, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I have a large XML File (1.7 GB) and I'm trying to apply UTF-8 encoding to it before importing into SQL server. Using powershell, it has been 1+ hour while converting and the system is completely useless because maximum memory usage. Can someone please suggest a more efficient way using powershell to encode this file? That's because I have several other files that will need to be converted. Thank you in advance for taking the time to reply.

This is the method currently in place:

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Folder\myfile.xml"
$destinationPath = "E:\Folder\myfile.xml"
Write-Host "Converting $_"
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName
Set-content (Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $_) -Encoding UTF8 -Value $content
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```bsh
[System.Io.File]::ReadAllText($sourcePath) | Out-File -FilePath $destinationPath -Encoding UTF8
```

Using the .NET classes is supposed to be faster.

Comment: I just tried that and here's how the code looks now:
$sourcePath = "C:\Folder\myfile.xml"
$destinationPath = "E:\Folder\myfile.xml"
Write-Host "Converting $_"
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName
Set-content (Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $_) -Encoding UTF8 -Value $content

Comment: thank you for replying.
I just tried and now it's:

$sourcePath = "C:\Folder\myfile.xml"
$destinationPath = "C:\Folder\myfile.xml"
[System.Io.File]::ReadAllText($sourcePath) | Out-File -FilePath $destinationPath -Encoding UTF8

Now, I'm getting:
Exception calling "ReadAllText" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Folder\' is denied."
At line:19 char:2
+  [System.Io.File]::ReadAllText($sourcePath) | Out-File -FilePath $des 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException